# How is possible to obtain similar RMSEs but very different Bias between two predictor models?

Tags: python, bias, rms

I'm comparing the results of two predictors models, CNN convolutional neural network and WRF weather numerical model, against a ground truth (Merra).

WRF-Merra is the weather numerical model vs Merra reanalysis.
CNN-Merra is the convolutional neural network vs Merra reanalysis.

I'm running the model for different times after the initialization and for each of them I have reasonable RMSE and Correlation coefficient results but very different Bias.

Here an example for the 18 hrs after the initialization:

```
rmse cnn-merra:  41.59755336876574
rmse wrf-merra:  44.698412696954215
bias cnn-merra:  -17.23248780747778
bias wrf-merra:  7.743057069935867
corr_wrf_merra:  0.9643024072814607
corr_cnn_merra:  0.972817697637590
```

Here for 24hrs after the initialization:

```
rmse_cnn-merra:  60.866766881390106
rmse_wrf-merra:  47.321850472005345
bias_cnn-merra:  -34.66534693047336
bias_wrf-merra:  6.556152471130599
corr_wrf_merra:  0.9604825847469841
corr_cnn_merra:  0.9688442121379363
```

Here how I computed the quantities with python (same for wrf_merra quantities):
RMSE `rmse_cnn_merra =sqrt(mean_squared_error(merra,cnn))`
Bias `bias_cnn_merra =np.average(cnn - actual)`
Corr coeff.`corr_cnn_merra=np.corrcoef(cnn, merra)[1,0]`

I would like to show you an example of the plots of cnn,wrf and merra for all the timesteps about the 24hrs after the initialization.

[image]
[image]
[image]

How is possible to have cnn-merra bias so negative? Where should I look first to explore this problem? I'm supposing that there is something wrong in the model but how can the RMSE seem reasonable?

This is my first approach with comparing results with different metrics so it's highly possible that my questions derive from a lack of theory.
Thanks